# Radar incidence angle of different images

Tags: angles, radar, sentinel-1

I am beginning in radar traitement, I want to know if working with radar image with differents incidence angle is not correct for result, Could the radar image have the same incidence angle for traitement and comparison?
I have images Sentinel 1 SLC with incidence angle = 34° and sentinel 1 GRD with incidence angle = 39°, 
I want to ask to some image Terrasar X to study merging work with those images but they ask me to give incidence angle, I don't know what to ask, because I want to work with those images and make traitement to compare with both SLC and GRD results, 
If I ask for example for an incidance angle=34° there will be no problem in traitement with GRD image? or I have to ask for an incidence angle between 34 and 39°?